# SSM Validation Exception Error - Inconsistent?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-ssm, aws-parameter-store

I am writing a userdata script that generates random strings for a set of SSM parameters. I am getting errors on all parameters except the last and can't understand why. I am thinking that the error is misleading.

Here is part of the script I am referencing:

```
url="myTestParam"

Params=("SQL_PASS", "WP_PASS", "HTTP_PASS")
for str in ${!Params[@]}
do
    echo $str
    aws ssm put-parameter --region us-east-1 --profile WPOpsAdmin --name "/qa/${url}/${Params[$str]}" --value $RANDOM --type "SecureString";
done
```

The output:

> 0
>
> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutParameter
> operation: Parameter name: can't be prefixed with "ssm"
> (case-insensitive). If formed as a path, it can consist of sub-paths
> divided by slash symbol; each sub-path can be formed as a mix of
> letters, numbers and the following 3 symbols .-_

> 1
>
> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the PutParameter
> operation: Parameter name: can't be prefixed with "ssm"
> (case-insensitive). If formed as a path, it can consist of sub-paths
> divided by slash symbol; each sub-path can be formed as a mix of
> letters, numbers and the following 3 symbols .-_

> 2
> {
> "Version": 1,
> "Tier": "Standard" }

So it seems to work correct only for the last index.

Comment: consider cutting-n-pasting your code (along with appropriate shebang) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and make the recommended changes; in particular you have problems with your array (run `typeset -p Params` to see contents of array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @markp-fuso for the suggestion. There was faulty syntax in the array.

These changes worked for me

```
#!/bin/bash

url="myTestParam"

Params=("SQL_PASS" "WP_PASS" "HTTP_PASS")
for str in "${!Params[@]}"
do
    echo "$str"
    aws ssm put-parameter --region us-east-1 --profile WPOpsAdmin --name "/qa/${url}/${Params[$str]}" --value $RANDOM --type "SecureString";
done
```

Comment: fwiw, `"${!Params[@]}"` gives you the indices for the array; since you never use the index (`$str`) by itself you could also go with `for param in "${Params[@]}"` (gives you the array values), `echo "${param}"` and `--name "/qa/${url}/${param}"` (direct value reference)

Comment: I liked that. It is much cleaner for sure.